# Add JList Items based on JComboBox selection

Tags: java, swing

When I click on a JComboBox item, I want it to display sentences in two different Jlists:

```
crosswordCategories = new JComboBox();

    crosswordCategories.addItem("Animals");
    crosswordCategories.addItem("Roman Empire");
    crosswordCategories.addItem("Geography");
    Object comboSelected = crosswordCategories.getSelectedItem();


    horizList = new JList();  
    horizList.setBounds(35, 430, 420, 170);
    horizList.setBackground(Color.white);
    horizList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
    add(horizList);


    vertList = new JList();  
    vertList.setBounds(490, 430, 420, 170);
    vertList.setBackground(Color.white);
    vertList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
    add(vertList);
```

If I click on the "Animals" category, it should display on the Horizontal JList "Big animal, with big ears and long nose." and on the Vertical JList "Man's best Friend.", just to put an example.

How do I do this? *It is for a crossword puzzle btw.

Edit: when the App starts, the JLists are empty.

Comment: You need to someway to associate the value in the combo to the value you want to display, something like a HashMap might do. You then need to kow when the selection changes in the combobox, someone like an AftionListener shouuold work. You then need add the value to the JList, probably using addItem

Answer (score 2):

- You need some way to associate the values in the `JComboBox` with the values you want to display, something kind a `Map` might do, but I'd prefer to use a POJO personally. See [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details
- You need to know when the `JComboBox` selection changes.  Something like an `ActionListener` would probably do. See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details
- Once the selection has changed, you need to get the selected item from the combo box (`getSelectedItem`), use the associated `Map` to look up the value and probably use `JList#addItem` to add the value to the `JList`, assuming you don't want to remove the existing items, otherwise, it would be quicker to just replace the `JList`'s model. See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

You may also want to take a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

You should also avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify